# JQuery integer value won't change?

Tags: jquery, integer

I have a function:

```
function my_function_name()
    {
        var $obj = $my_object;
        var idx = Number($obj.order);
        var newIndex = idx+1;
    }
```

"newIndex" is NOT "idx + 1" but simply the same value as "idx". "$obj.order" is holding an integer value.

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Can you post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or at least give us a bit more code? We have no idea what `$my_object` looks like or where it comes from. Also, the posted code is pure JavaScript, none of that is jQuery. Your variable names just happen to start with the `$` character (unless `$my_object` is a jQuery object, but we don't know if it is or not). Also, as far as I can see, the posted code should work, assuming `$obj.order` is indeed a value parsable to a number.

Comment: I tried to simulate your error but it works fine [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/uqojiz/1/edit), what is the content of $my_object?

Comment: I am gonna guess your print out statement is wrong and you are printing idx instead of newIndex. The code looks fine as long as your object returns the expected values

Comment: Good point, @Huangism. How do you know `newIndex` does actually have the wrong value? What are you doing to view its value? Are you certain you're looking at the right variable?

Answer (score 0):

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/9JJ5D/)

```
function num(i) {
    this.order = i;
}


$my_object = new num(10);

var $obj = $my_object;
var idx = Number($obj.order);
var newIndex = idx + 1;
```

As per your question `newIndex` should have `10` , But i am getting `11` in output(see fiddle)